# Ubuntu 20.04: A Google Drive Client that works in 2020

Tags: 20.04, google-drive

I Have been doing some reading on google drive clients (that sync). Most applications / posts are outdated or very inactive.

After comparing some i went for odrive & vgrive but both don't work.

1. odrive:

On first start pops up login for google but it complains that the browser is not secure enough (it is a web browser in the pop up itself)

2. vgrive:

I get it up and running and it seems to start syncing, but when i look at the files content its some error message that their are to many queries to the google api's and that for security reasons its blocked.

Does anyone know how i can get them up and running or has a good and secure and free alternative?

Also some alternative idea i had:
Ubuntu has a build in mapping to google drive (not syncing) could i use a normal syncing tool that syncs this mapped folder with a normal folder?

I would prefer to have a client software that does all the work.

Comment: Insync (https://www.insynchq.com/) works, but it costs $

Comment: Not so much a client but I use google-drive-ocamlfuse with mountpoints so my Google drive is pretty much just like any other local directory. Then I use rsync scripts to sync/backup folders/data. https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse I have not tried Ubuntu google drive map with rsync but that might work too.

Comment: @OrganicMarble i found that to, but i was looking for something free, i edited my post. Thanks for the input tough

Comment: @codlord, i would prefer some straight forward app that does this. but i can use this as a backup idea. Thnks!